# Subclassing int - unexpected behaviour with range

Tags: python-3.x, reference, int, subclassing

We've tried to create a mutable int which references its value from somewhere else. It *appears* to behave in most cases, however, when handing it to the range we get an unexpected result.

The subclass contains a bunch of boilerplate so I'll include the methods I know are called by range to infer the int's value which will reproduce the behavior.

```
class IntRef(int):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reference = 5
        super().__init__()

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.reference.__le__(other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.reference.__sub__(other)

    ...
```

This the behaviour:

```
a = IntRef()
list(range(a)) # [] not [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I believe we have implemented all of the Dunder methods associated with an int so I would expect range create a zero - 4 list.

Does range make an assumption about where the 'value' is stored on an int type class when finding its value? What's the best way to go about making a transparent reference-type box in Python?

Thanks

Comment: How should `range` know that it should access the `reference` attribute of its argument? In other words, it simply thinks you pass `0`: `a = IntRef() ; 
print(a) # 0`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't subclass `int` and then override all of the methods.  If you do that, the base class will think you have one value, and the subclass will think you have a different value.  Instead, subclass [`numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) and implement all of the abstract methods.  Then you can be sure your implementation is the only game in town.

Comment: Great. Sounds like the kind of thing I'm looking for. Do you know if there is a performance hit from subclass ingredients integral?

Comment: @freebie: Python integers are implemented in C, so I suppose they are very slightly faster, but unless you have a representative benchmark of your use case, this is probably not the sort of micro-optimization you want to be doing.  You (presumably) chose Python because it's readable, not because it's fast.

Comment: Very true. I was just curious as the overhead of using a pure python UserDict, where you might only access it a few times, would be very negligible. Though I felt doing the same for a primitive type that I would assume would be accessed way more might have a much more considerable impact. I guess I'll find out. I'll give the Intergral a shot and reward you the answer if all checks out. Thanks again

Comment: This appears to break down if I try and divide a float by my Integral. I don't know if I'm able to get what I'm after

Comment: @freebie: That's a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything different in `IntRef.__new__` so by calling `IntRef()` and using `int.__new__` you get back a value of `0`.

Define an appropriate `IntRef.__new__`:

```
class IntRef(int):

    def __new__(cls, reference=5, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, reference, *args, **kwargs)
```

and you'll get the wanted result:

```
a = IntRef()
list(range(a))
Out[78]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but using an argument seems weird and confusing; I'd just stick with the default int behavior and initialize `IntRef` with `IntRef(5)`.

Comment: I'd go with a default value `0` to keep compatibility with other types in Python. ie `int(), float(), list(), set()` etc all return their corresponding "zero value": `0, 0.0, [], {}`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify a bit: I want to be able to change the value of the IntRef.reference object at runtime - which I don't believe this allows. I had wrote a __new__ and __init__ method implantation but didn't think to included - I should have.

Comment: @freebie though I haven't tested this, you'd probably be able to do this by making `reference` a property and returning a new instance of `IntRef` (by initializing a new `IntRef` object inside the property implementation) when `reference` is accessed.